# Slave serial number 5 more than master DNS server

Tags: dns

We have a situation where the records from master DNS server did not get updated in  the slave DNS servers because the slave DNS server's serial number was higher than the master's. How could it be? Any thoughts please?

Comment: What OS is running on the DNS servers?

Answer (score 2):

Slave only gets data from master. So if slave has serial `123456` that is because master once upon a time sent it zone with serial `123456`. In other words, somebody some time in the past put the wrong (high) serial on the master and slave picked it up, and after that moment slave will refuse all updates with serial smaller than the one it has. Somebody noticed the error and corrected serial on master, but (s)he was too late as changes already propagated.

Possible solutions are:

1. (better) update the master to have new serial which is higher than all serials on all slaves. It will then propagate and fix all slaves automatically. Unfortunately it might mean giving up on recommended YYYYMMDDX format for serial (or not - depending on the exact problem. It could be fixed later with wraparound fix).
2. (worse) manually remove zones on corrupted slaves and restart their nameservers. They will then fetch the zone with serial from master and be ok. But note that in this case caching nameservers around the world will keep stale data for time specified in SOA record which might be a problem, depending on your case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Matija. Unfortunately we do not modify the serial number manually. It goes by IPAM deployments. We did rndc clean on the one zone having issue and redeployed the slaves, which resolved the issue. I was wondering on what caused it.

Comment: @san perhaps a master DNS machine had a wrong date/time? maybe if it was rebooted and pulled time from RTC which was out of sync, and name server started before NTP could sync time? If you turn on more detailed transfer logs for AXFR/IXFR, you'll have trail to debug if it happens next time.